# Does it make sense categorizing entries that are tagged?

Tags: django, tagging

The reason for this is that I want somewhat categorized permalinks. Let's say I file a bug and I want the permalink to be `/css/ie-bug/` while being tagged as `floats, double-margin, margin`.

Would it go against the whole purpose of having tags by not tagging this as `css` but instead categorizing the entry? I would also not tag this as `internet-explorer` but instead categorize it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'd do it the same way. Permalinks (or permalink prefixes) and tags are not the same thing. Tags is very dynamic metadata that gives you the most important properties of your questions. Permalinks are (of course) static and very permanent data that shouldn't be more as a link. So using this logic it's very normal to use a different extra datamodel for permalinks, even if it introduces categories next to tags.

Just my two cents of course.

Comment: How would you actually save the permalinks? Since I already have a slug field I would add my new Category dropdown field, would I have to re-save the slug field behind the scenes in the `save` method or is there a more straightforward way?